# Subscribed calendars not visible in Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I have subscribed calendars in my Outlook (subscribed to using feed links), and I want to get the id of these calendars. Following Microsoft's API, a `GET` Request on `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars` using Microsoft Graph Explorer only shows my Outlook calendar and not the calendars that I have subscribed to. How can I make them visible?

Comment: I have tried it from my end using Outlook on the Web, going to Calendar--> Add Calendar--> Subscribe from Web--> Give the link and Save. I used the same call and it worked for me. Have you done the same?

Comment: Moving this to Answer

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it from my end using Outlook on the Web, going to

`Calendar--> Add Calendar--> Subscribe from Web--> Give the link and Save`.

I used the same call and it worked for me.